# Getters and Setters in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, getter-setter

In Java, for example, I can write getters on my own (generated by IDE) or use Annotations like @Getter in lombok - which was pretty simple.

Kotlin however has [getters and setters by default](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html).
But I can't understand how to use them.

I want to make it, lets say - similar to Java:

```
private val isEmpty: String
        get() = this.toString() //making this thing public rises an error: Getter visibility must be the same as property visibility.
```

So how do getters work?

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Getters and setters are auto-generated in Kotlin. If you write:

```
val isEmpty: Boolean
```

It is equal to the following Java code:

```
private final Boolean isEmpty;

public Boolean isEmpty() {
    return isEmpty;
}
```

In your case the private access modifier is redundant - isEmpty is private by default and can be accessed only by a getter. When you try to get your object's isEmpty property you call the get method in real. For more understanding of getters/setters in Kotlin: the two code samples below are equal:

```
var someProperty: String = "defaultValue"
```

and

```
var someProperty: String = "defaultValue"
    get() = field
    set(value) { field = value }
```

Also I want to point out that `this` in a getter is not your property - it's the class instance. If you want to get access to the field's value in a getter or setter you can use the reserved word `field` for it:

```
val isEmpty: Boolean
  get() = field
```

If you only want to have a get method in public access - you can write this code:

```
var isEmpty: Boolean
    private set
```

due to the private modifier near the set accessor you can set this value only in methods inside your object.

Comment: `In your case the private access modifier is redundant` How? Kotlin doc's say default modifier is public. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html

Comment: @Nothing yes it seems like public field, but under hood you call getter method

Comment: The `val isEmpty: Boolean` will not compile as isEmpty is not yet initialized, right? Just starting to learn Kotlin. Also, what is happening with `get() = field`?

Comment: great explanation, imho the Kotlin docs are hard to understand unless you're already familiar with the language...

Comment: Why doesn't Kotlin make use of private modifiers more often. Seems to be like all libraries' variables are public.

Comment: What about if you want to use an observable with a private setter? ie: so you can perform some reactive logic when the value is set?

Comment: This is not equal to the code you mentioned. The generated getter/setter are final, which makes difference in the case when accessors get overridden in the extended proxy class. E.g. Hibernate uses this approach a lot.

Comment: downvote for object wrapper `Boolean` in Java, it should be primitive `boolean` (unless nullable, of course)

Answer (score 37):

The rules about property accessors [visibility modifiers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#visibility-modifiers) are the following:

- Getter visibility of `var` and `val` property should be exactly **the same** to the visibility of the property, thus you can only explicitly duplicate the property modifier, but it is redundant:

  ```
  protected val x: Int
      protected get() = 0 // No need in `protected` here.
  ```
- Setter visibility of `var` property should be  **the same or less permissive** than the property visibility:

  ```
  protected var x: Int
      get() = 0
      private set(x: Int) { } // Only `private` and `protected` are allowed.
  ```

In Kotlin, properties are always accessed through getter and setter, thus there's no need in making a property `private` with `public` accessors like in Java -- [its backing field (if present)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) is already private. So, visibility modifiers on property accessors are only used to make setter visibility less permissive:

- For a property with backing field and default accessors:

  ```
  var x = 0 // `public` by default
      private set
  ```
- For a property without backing field:

  ```
  var x: Int // `public` by default
      get() = 0
      protected set(value: Int) { }
  ```

Comment: Can one set and get different types ? Setting `x`  equal to some `"Some String"` and returning say the length, `11`, of the string ?

Comment: @Carel, no, as of now, this use case is not supported: the accessors of a property should operate with exactly the type of the property. Using a different type is covered by using a [separate backing property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-properties)

Comment: Darn, Kotlin is so very close to Python that you think it'll just work when you get reminded it's typed... and cut your own throat.

Comment: Thanks for access modifiers. I removed `private` from a variable, and it became accessible from another class with getter.

Comment: I get a "Private setters are not allowed for open properties" when using the "var x//private set" combination. Resolved by declaring as "final var x"

Answer (score 28):

1) Example default `setter` and `getter` for **property** `firstName` in Kotlin

```
class Person {
    var firstName: String = ""
            get() = field       // field here ~ `this.firstName` in Java or normally `_firstName` is C#
            set(value) {
                field = value
            }

}
```

Using

```
val p = Person()
p.firstName = "A"  // access setter
println(p.firstName) // access getter (output:A)
```

**IF** your `setter` or `getter` is **exactly same** above, you can remove it because it is **unnecessary**

2) Example custom setter and getter.

```
const val PREFIX = "[ABC]"

class Person {

    // set: if value set to first name have length < 1 => throw error else add prefix "ABC" to the name
    // get: if name is not empty -> trim for remove whitespace and add '.' else return default name
    var lastName: String = ""
        get() {
            if (!field.isEmpty()) {
                return field.trim() + "."
            }
            return field
        }
        set(value) {
            if (value.length > 1) {
                field = PREFIX + value
            } else {
                throw IllegalArgumentException("Last name too short")
            }
        }
}
```

Using

```
val p = Person()
p.lastName = "DE         " // input with many white space
println(p.lastName)  // output:[ABC]DE.
p.lastName = "D" // IllegalArgumentException since name length < 1
```

**More**
I start learn Kotlin from Java so I am confusing about `field` and `property` because in Java there is no `property`.
After some search, I see `field` and `property` in Kotlin look like C#  ([What is the difference between a field and a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property))

Here is some relevant post which talk about `field` and `property` in Java and Kotlin.
[does java have something similar to C# properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963243/does-java-have-something-similar-to-c-sharp-properties)
https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/kotlin-programmer-dictionary-field-vs-property-30ab7ef70531

Correct me if I am wrong. Hope it help

Comment: Thank you, it really help me!

Answer (score 10):

Getter in kotlin is by default public, but you can set the setter to private and set the value by using one method inside a class. Like this.

```
/**
* Created by leo on 17/06/17.*/

package foo
class Person() {
var name: String = "defaultValue"
               private set

fun foo(bar: String) {
    name = bar // name can be set here
       }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  var p = Person()
  println("Name of the person is ${p.name}")
  p.foo("Jhon Doe")
  println("Name of the person is ${p.name}")
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you have a Var then you can:

```
var property: String = "defVal"
              get() = field
              set(value) { field = value }
```

But in the case of Val, you can not set it once assigned, so there won't be a setter block:

```
val property: String = "defVal"
              get() = field
```

or if you don't want setter then:

```
val property: String = "defVal"
              private set
```

Comment: Be careful when converting from Java to Kotlin as the AI engine will often move the setter and getter of Java a variable to its own function in Kotlin, such as getProperty(). This will cause all sorts of bugs. You need to implement the solution posted by Ali.

Answer (score 6):

You can see this tutorial for more info:

[Yet Another Kotlin Tutorial for Android Developers](https://codete.com/blog/yet-another-kotlin-tutorial-android-developers-part-1/)

> Properties
>
> In Kotlin world, classes cannot have fields, just properties. var
>   keyword tells us the property is mutable, in contrast to val. Let’s
>   see an example:
>
> ```
> class Contact(var number: String) {
>
>    var firstName: String? = null
>    var lastName: String? = null
>    private val hasPrefix : Boolean
>        get() = number.startsWith("+")
>
> }
> ```
>
> There is not much code, but lots of things are happening behind the
>   scenes. **We will go through it step by step. First of all, we created a
>   public final class Contact.**
>
> This is the primary rule we have to face: if not specified otherwise,
>   classes are public and final by default (by the way, the same is for
>   class methods). If you want to inherit from class, mark it with open
>   keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a practical, real world example of a Kotlin getter and setter (See more details [here](https://medium.com/swlh/kotlin-property-getters-and-setters-17ffb5a71b98)):

```
// Custom Getter
val friendlyDescription get(): String {
    val isNeighborhood = district != null
    var description = if (isNeighborhood) "Neighborhood" else "City"
    description += " in"
    if (isNeighborhood) {
        description += " $city,"
    }
    province?.let {
        if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
            description += " $it,"
        }
    }
    description += " $country"
    return description
}

print(myLocation.friendlyDescription) // "Neighborhood in Denver, Colorado, United States"


// Custom Setter
enum class SearchResultType {
    HISTORY, SAVED, BASIC
}

private lateinit var resultTypeString: String

var resultType: SearchResultType
    get() {
        return enumValueOf(resultTypeString)
    }
    set(value) {
        resultTypeString = value.toString()
    }

result.resultType = SearchResultType.HISTORY
print(result.resultTypeString) // "HISTORY"
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit disagree with @Cortwave top answer. **Kotlin** member fields *by default* *are final, not private*. You have to write private modifier *to make it* *encapsulated* within the class.

The answer I was looking for here is does kotlin autogenerate getters and setters for private member fields or you have to do it on your own? Straightforward implementation in Android Studio shows you need to write it by yourself.