# In kotlin, how to make the setter of properties in primary constructor private?

Tags: constructor, kotlin

In kotlin, how to make the setter of properties in primary constructor private?

```
class City(val id: String, var name: String, var description: String = "") {

    fun update(name: String, description: String? = "") {
        this.name = name
        this.description = description ?: this.description
    }
}
```

I  want the setter of properties `name` to be private, and the getter of it public, how can I do?

Comment: check it https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40438571/kotlin-understanding-getters-and-setters

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The solution is to create a property outside of constructor and set setter's visibility.

```
class Sample(var id: Int, name: String) {

    var name: String = name
        private set

}
```

**Update:**
They're discussing it here: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/private-setter-for-var-in-primary-constructor/3640

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
class Sample(var id: Int, private var name:String) {

    // Backing field
    var _name: String = ""
        get() = name
        private set

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
     println("Hello World")

     val sample = Sample(1, "hello")
    //    println(sample.name); It's not possible
    println(sample._name)
}
```

Comment: I think would switch the naming though. `_name` in the constructor, and `name` for the property.

Comment: You will end up having two names. After `_name`'s `set`, `get`'s return value won't change.

Comment: Adding secondary constructor may be a better solution

Comment: As @Miha_x64 points out, you have to implement the setter of the "backing field" so that it changes the constructor field.