# Kotlin custom Getter makes `val` and `var` confusing?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, `var` is mutable and `val` should be assigned only once.

However, consider `val foo` in the following example:

```
var counter = 0

val foo: String
  get(){
    counter++
    return "val$counter"
  }

fun main(): String {
    val a = foo
    val b = foo
    val c = foo
    return "we got: $a $b $c"
    // output: we got: val1 val2 val3
}
```

The `get()` method is executed each time we try to access `foo`, resulting **different values for val**.

Since the value of `foo` is changing, I tried to use `var`. The compiler then complained about "Property must be initialized". So I had to give it a default value:

```
var foo: String = "default value that will never be used"
  get(){
    counter++
    return "val$counter"
  }
```

I don't like either approach here. What's the correct practice?

Comment: While the answers are explaining why it's allowed and how it works, none of them gave the correct answer: you should _not_ do that in the first place. Your `foo` property is not a property, but a function with side effects. By doing something like that, you're breaking all the assumptions that users of your property can make.

Comment: Using either `var` or `val` should only affect `foo`, not anything else. You should _not_ use that, and that's why you have this question in the first place. Saying "I wanted to use `var`" is just wanting to go against the idioms of the language.

Comment: That's exactly my point. There's nothing wrong in implementing `List.size` as a property, because it doesn't have any side effects. Implementing `List.pop` as a property, on the other hand, wouldn't make any sense, because it does alter the state of the list just by reading it. Which is exactly what you're describing here: reading `foo` would change `counter`.

Comment: I obviously can't speak for the language designers, but something like `DateTime.now` would be fine as a property, in my opinion. The difference between this and `foo` in your question being that while `DateTime.now`'s value change over time, it's not altered by the fact that you read it or not (in addition to not changing anything else either, which is even worse).

Comment: I think from your comment that what you're looking for might be a lazy property or the `lateinit` keyword. (I think that this conversation might actually have some value to any potential reader confused about val, var, and properties in general)

Comment: @MarcPlano-Lesay `lateinit` modifier is not allowed on properties with a custom getter or setter; `lazy` would only execute once so the value will not change on subsequent calls. I still don't think this whole wall of texts will help further readers. I will delete all mine and you can leave a more concise comment if you would like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In Kotlin, var is mutable and val should be assigned only once.

For local variables, yes. For properties, not really: `val` means "only has a getter", `var` means "has both a getter and a setter". This getter (and setter) is allowed to do pretty much anything. You could just return a random value each time, for example.

An exception is reassigning the backing field for a `val`:

```
val foo: Int = 0
  get(){
    field++
    return field
  }
```

won't compile.

Answer (score 3):

This is already reported in YouTrack, as [KT-16681](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16681), "kotlin allows mutating the field of read-only property".

As you can see in the reply in KT-16681, the custom getter is compiled into another function, which makes field `foo` and method `getFoo()` become two unrelated things.

Also from the reply in KT-16681, this kind of violation (Reassignment of read-only property via backing field) will produce an error since Kotlin 1.3.

**Update:** In comment, the original poster mentioned that `KT-16681` is different from this question. However, inspired from that issue, we can see Kotlin bytecode there by `Tools -> Kotlin -> Show Kotlin Bytecode` (removed metadata etc.):

```
public final class Test53699029Kt {


  // access flags 0xA
  private static I counter

  // access flags 0x19
  public final static getCounter()I
   L0
    LINENUMBER 3 L0
    GETSTATIC Test53699029Kt.counter : I
    IRETURN
   L1
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 0

  // access flags 0x19
  public final static setCounter(I)V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 3 L0
    ILOAD 0
    PUTSTATIC Test53699029Kt.counter : I
    RETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE <set-?> I L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  // access flags 0x19
  public final static getFoo()Ljava/lang/String;
  @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible
   L0
    LINENUMBER 7 L0
    GETSTATIC Test53699029Kt.counter : I
    DUP
    ISTORE 0
    ICONST_1
    IADD
    PUTSTATIC Test53699029Kt.counter : I
   L1
    LINENUMBER 8 L1
    NEW java/lang/StringBuilder
    DUP
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/StringBuilder.<init> ()V
    LDC "val"
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    GETSTATIC Test53699029Kt.counter : I
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.toString ()Ljava/lang/String;
    ARETURN
   L2
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  // access flags 0x19
  public final static main()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 12 L0
    INVOKESTATIC Test53699029Kt.getFoo ()Ljava/lang/String;
    ASTORE 0
   L1
    LINENUMBER 13 L1
    INVOKESTATIC Test53699029Kt.getFoo ()Ljava/lang/String;
    ASTORE 1
   L2
    LINENUMBER 14 L2
    INVOKESTATIC Test53699029Kt.getFoo ()Ljava/lang/String;
    ASTORE 2
   L3
    LINENUMBER 15 L3
    NEW java/lang/StringBuilder
    DUP
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/StringBuilder.<init> ()V
    LDC "we got: "
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    BIPUSH 32
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (C)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    BIPUSH 32
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (C)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    ALOAD 2
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.toString ()Ljava/lang/String;
    ASTORE 3
   L4
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    ALOAD 3
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   L5
   L6
    LINENUMBER 17 L6
    RETURN
   L7
    LOCALVARIABLE c Ljava/lang/String; L3 L7 2
    LOCALVARIABLE b Ljava/lang/String; L2 L7 1
    LOCALVARIABLE a Ljava/lang/String; L1 L7 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 4

  // access flags 0x1009
  public static synthetic main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    INVOKESTATIC Test53699029Kt.main ()V
    RETURN
    MAXSTACK = 0
    MAXLOCALS = 1
```

As we can see, there is no field for `foo`, just a `getFoo()`, comparing for a normal `val` declaration:

```
public final class Test53699029Kt {


  // access flags 0xA
  private static I counter

  // access flags 0x19
  public final static getCounter()I
   L0
    LINENUMBER 1 L0
    GETSTATIC Test53699029Kt.counter : I
    IRETURN
   L1
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 0

  // access flags 0x19
  public final static setCounter(I)V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 1 L0
    ILOAD 0
    PUTSTATIC Test53699029Kt.counter : I
    RETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE <set-?> I L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  // access flags 0x1A
  private final static Ljava/lang/String; foo = "aaa"
  @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible

  // access flags 0x19
  public final static getFoo()Ljava/lang/String;
  @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible
   L0
    LINENUMBER 3 L0
    GETSTATIC Test53699029Kt.foo : Ljava/lang/String;
    ARETURN
   L1
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 0

  // access flags 0x19
  public final static main()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 6 L0
    GETSTATIC Test53699029Kt.foo : Ljava/lang/String;
    ASTORE 0
   L1
    LINENUMBER 7 L1
    GETSTATIC Test53699029Kt.foo : Ljava/lang/String;
    ASTORE 1
   L2
    LINENUMBER 8 L2
    GETSTATIC Test53699029Kt.foo : Ljava/lang/String;
    ASTORE 2
   L3
    LINENUMBER 9 L3
    NEW java/lang/StringBuilder
    DUP
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/StringBuilder.<init> ()V
    LDC "we got: "
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    BIPUSH 32
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (C)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    BIPUSH 32
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (C)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    ALOAD 2
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.toString ()Ljava/lang/String;
    ASTORE 3
   L4
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    ALOAD 3
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   L5
   L6
    LINENUMBER 11 L6
    RETURN
   L7
    LOCALVARIABLE c Ljava/lang/String; L3 L7 2
    LOCALVARIABLE b Ljava/lang/String; L2 L7 1
    LOCALVARIABLE a Ljava/lang/String; L1 L7 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 4

  // access flags 0x1009
  public static synthetic main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    INVOKESTATIC Test53699029Kt.main ()V
    RETURN
    MAXSTACK = 0
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  // access flags 0x8
  static <clinit>()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 3 L0
    LDC "aaa"
    PUTSTATIC Test53699029Kt.foo : Ljava/lang/String;
    RETURN
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 0
```

using `val foo = "aaa"` will produce a normal `final static String foo` field and `final static String getFoo()` method, but using `val foo: String` with `get()` will not produce that field, just produce a method. This getter function is generated by Kotlin, I believe the lost of field comes from the lost of initial assignment in declaration of `val`, but I can't find the real documentation of that, in question like [Getters and Setters in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906607/getters-and-setters-in-kotlin) just directly use this conclusion.

So, this seems a bypass for modification of `final static`.

Problems occur when an immutable field referenced a mutable field. `val` is not re-assignable, but it referenced a `var`, a re-assignable field, this results in the modification of `val`.

Comment: KT-16681 talks about reassigning the backing field in a getter, e.g. `field = "changed"`. But in my example, no one is reassigning the backing field. The `counter++` statement could as well happen in `main()` function or any other parts of the program.

Comment: @user1032613 I updated my answer, but I am not sure if this update fits your question.

Comment: This is definitely a bug and still exists in the kotlin version 1.8.10.  I don't care how it is implemented--I want consistency: **vals** should be immutable.