# What is the difference between textView.setText(string) and textView.text = $string

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi I am making a app with **Kotlin** and I found that I can both use

```
textView.setText(str)
```

and

```
textView.text = $str
```

I wanna know what I should use and the differences between them.
Thank you.

Comment: It's basically the same, but .setText() is the java syntax.

Comment: First one is conventional  setters for java and second one is a property setter used in kotlin .. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906607/getters-and-setters-in-kotlin). Basically both are same .

Comment: This: `textView.text = $str` does not even compile. Did you mean: `textView.text = "$str"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're the same **in most cases**, basically Kotlin generates a synthetic property for the class attributes based on their getter, which you can use to assign values to and get values from.

```
//So, for most cases
textView.setText("some value");
//Is the same as
textView.text = "some value"
//The second is simply shorter and is the 'kotlin way' of assigning values
```

#### Now, here's the catch -

In most cases, this works fine. But, as mentioned, the synthetic property is generated from the getter, if there is a setter as well, then issues arise. The reason is that the getter and the setter **may** have different types. For example, `EditText` has `Editable` getter, now, kotlin creates a synthetic property `text` of the type `Editable`.

```
editText.setText("some value"); //Works
editText.text = "some value" //Won't work, will show an error stating that expected type is Editable
```

Answer (score 0):

`textView.setText(str)` and `textView.text = $str`, does the same job of setting the specified `str` to `TextView`. The only difference I can come up with is,

`textView.setText(str)  // old Java way of setting Text` where **method** setText(str) was being called.

`textView.text = $str //new Kotlin way of setting Text` where instead of a method, a **synthetic property** is being called.

Answer (score 0):

As in the Kotlin, you are not using `findViewById`

so to access your textView, import statement must be like  this

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<layout>.*
```

And `textView.text = $str` is the Synthetic Property access provided by Kotlin Plugin for android

You can use both, not much difference in the usability, but for the easier code writing
this would be better

For more information, read this https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

Both works the same way.

Java Convention

```
textView.setText(“…”)
```

Kotlin Convention

```
textView.text=”…”
```

“Methods that follow the Java conventions for getters and setters (no-argument methods with names starting with get and single-argument methods with names starting with set) are represented as properties in Kotlin.”- [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html)

thus `textView.text=”…”` instead of `textView.setText(“…”)` if you are using Kotlin to follow Kotlin Conventions.

Ref - [Begin Kotlin; from an Activity, a Button and a TextView](https://medium.com/@gitudrebel94/begin-kotlin-from-an-activity-a-button-and-a-textview-50e0394aecc2)

Answer (score 0):

The method `setText()` and `getText()` are called setters and getters, they are automatically generated in kotlin.

```
class ClassName{
    var name: String= "some_value"
}
```

You can use the `name` property directly with the object of the class or you can also use the auto-generated `setter` method.

```
class Another{
    var c = ClassName()

    c.name = "value"
    c.setName("value")
}
```

But if a property starts with a `val` instead of `var` then it  is immutable and does not allow a `setter`.
In case you want to read further:-
[Setters and getters in kotlin](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/getters-setters)