# What's difference between edittext.setText("str") and edittext.text="str" in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

It's the same function when I jumped to the implementation of the function.
What are they different for under the hood?

To use `textView.setText("str")` with `TextView` is okay.
But to use `editText.setText("str")` with `EditText` is not okay, even if `setText(...)` is the same.

In case of `EditText` I have to use `setText("str")`.
What's the reason for that in Kotlin?

Comment: What is `EditTextView`? You meant `EditText`?

Comment: `EditText` is right. I'll edit it.

Comment: is this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57056445/what-is-the-difference-between-textview-settextstring-and-textview-text-str/57056861

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting text in EditText Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493908/setting-text-in-edittext-kotlin)

Comment: It's because of the naming of `text` so it guess  not `public final void setText(CharSequence text)` of TextView but `public Editable getText()` of EditText because of synthetic property. Got it! Thanks for everyone.