# Why am I able to access a .arguments property in Fragments?

Tags: android, kotlin

The `Fragment` class appears to have [`.setArgument()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#setarguments) and [`.getArgument()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#getarguments) methods, but no `.arguments` property. Why am I able to access such an argument?

```
var inputFragment: InputFragment = InputFragment()
inputFragment.arguments = intent.extras
```

Similarly, I am able to access what appears to be an `.intent` property within an `Activity`. Control-clicking on these classes leads me to the get methods for these "properties" within a .java file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getters and Setters in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906607/getters-and-setters-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be due to Java/Kotlin interop.

Kotlin [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters) for *Calling Java from Kotlin > Getters and setters* state:

> Methods that follow the Java conventions for getters and setters (no-argument methods with names starting with `get` and single-argument methods with names starting with `set`) are represented as properties in Kotlin.

> ```
> if (calendar.firstDayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY) {  // call getFirstDayOfWeek()
>     calendar.firstDayOfWeek = Calendar.MONDAY // call setFirstDayOfWeek()
> }
> ```

The classes in question would originally be written in either Java or Kotlin. My guess is it's really in Java with `getFoo()` and `setFoo()` methods, just that those particular Android docs have the option to switch between view modes for the two different languages in an automated fashion, thus not accounting for this type of special case.

Which, would explain me being able to validly use `.arguments` in Kotlin, despite the docs showing entire `getArgument()` and `setArgument()` methods in both its Java and Kotlin views.

And would also explain me seeing entire get methods in `.java` files when control-clicking valid properties like `.intent` from my `.kt` files, in the IDE I was using (Android Studio).

Worth noting that the inverse (*Calling Kotlin from Java > Properties*) can be found [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#properties), which states:

> A Kotlin property is compiled to the following Java elements:
>
> - a getter method, with the name calculated by prepending the `get` prefix
> - a setter method, with the name calculated by prepending the `set` prefix (only for `var` properties)
> - a private field, with the same name as the property name (only for properties with backing fields)
>
> For example, `var firstName: String` compiles to the following Java declarations:
>
> ```
> private String firstName;
>
> public String getFirstName() {
>     return firstName;
> }
>
> public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
>     this.firstName = firstName;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
inputFragment.arguments = intent.extras
```

is the Kotlin equivalent to

```
inputFragment.setArguments(intent.extras);
```

in Java.

the same holds true for accessing the value:

```
println(inputFragment.arguments)
```

is the same as

```
System.out.println(inputFragment.getArguments());
```

you can read more about the default getter and setter in the [reference guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html).