# Java - Unable to get private String that was set from a local method

Tags: java, oop, gwt, syntax

I feel stupid asking this and searched [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36102768/java-get-set-methods) but I don't understand why I'm able to set `private String title` but unable to get it.

I have a class that makes an HTTP request to get some JSON, parse it and set the instance variables from `processResponse()`. When I use `GWT.log()` inside `setTitle()` and `getTitle()`, the console shows that `setTitle()` has the value but `getTitle()` is `undefined`.

I'm using GWT if that makes a difference. This class will be used to create objects and these variables will be used throughout the program. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public class Requester {
    //other variables
    private String title;

    public Requester(UrlBuilder url) {
        this.setURL(url);
        this.generateRequest();
    }

    public void setURL(UrlBuilder url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    private void generateRequest() {
        RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, URL.encode(url.getUrl()));
        builder.setHeader("Authorization", authHeader);

        try {
            builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
                // onError() method

                public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                    processResponse(response);
                }

            });
        } catch (RequestException e) {
            //exception code
        }
    }

    private void processResponse(Response response) {
        //code to get title and assign it to String output
        setTitle(output);
    }

    private void setTitle(String output) {
        this.title = output;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `processResponse` method, where/how are you accessing the variable `output` that is used as a parameter to `setTitle`?

Comment: If `setTitle` is called and sets a particular value, and a subsequent call to `getTitle` shows `null`, then it is not the same *instance* of `Requester`. The calling code is making the call on another `Requester` object. Insert log statement into constructor to confirm, then look at code making the calls, since problem is *there*, not here in this code.

Comment: @ChrisSprague I declared a local String for the assignment - `String output = jsonArray.get(0).isObject().get("title").toString();`

Comment: It is bad form to execute lots of logic (especially integration logic such as making a web request) in an object's constructor.  You probably want  a separate method for making your web request that can be called after the object is constructed.  This will help avoid possible state issues like the one @Andreas mentioned.  Constructors are for constructing the object, not necessarily initializing it (use a separate init() method for that if you must)

Comment: @java-addict301 That was really good advice. Not executing logic inside the constructor made things simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the problem with the help from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45360151/gwt-how-to-return-a-string-value-from-requestbuilder-after-receiving-a-respons) that I had asked.

The asynchronous call to `generateRequest()` had not finished by the time I was calling `getTitle()`. Since `title` was not set at that point, I was getting `undefined`.

Based on the suggestions in the other question, I modified my code to execute a method where `title` was passed as a parameter after `generateRequest()` was done -

```
public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                    MyOtherClass.newMethod(processResponse(response));
                }
```